# Need to remove an Object from DCOM config (DCOMCNFG)

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, dcom

We have an application with activex exe and a com dll. After installing we get an object created in DCOM config.

If we try to delete this object from DCOM config, it goes off till we again reopen it. 
Want to know if there's any procedure to delete this object completely from DCOM and its registries.

Answer (score 4):

No idea why this would be tagged VB.Net, but...

You can remove most of the server's registration entries by running the EXE with a command line switch as in:

```
MyAx.EXE /unregserver
```

However this leaves a system-synthesized entry under `HKCR\AppID` after first use.

As far as I know you must manually remove this since the compiled program has no idea the key was ever created (i.e. it did not do this itself).

See [DCOMCNFG and AppID.exe mapping and implications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246054)

Comment: Thanks Bob for your response on this. 
We have tried unregistering as you said and also with regsvr32, but didn't got success.

Comment: If we try to remove the entry manually, will it impact the system ?

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.  "Impact the system?"  What system?  Your application?  If you want the application to work then why do you want to remove the registry entries (per original question above)?  Maybe try asking a new question phrased by a native English-speaking programmer?

Answer (score 2):

Search for the Application ID in the registry and delete all keys that contain a reference to it.
Apologies for replying to an old post, but I just had to do this today to clean up a corrupted Altiris Agent uninstall.