# How to delete an entry from DCOM config?

Tags: com, activex, dcom, windows-xp-sp3

Need to understand what specific registry entries corresponds to an entry showing up in DCOM config(DCOMCNFG).

If want to delete an object's entry from DCOM config, how it can be achieved?

Comment: REad this article.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487609/need-to-remove-an-object-from-dcom-config-dcomcnfg][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17487609/need-to-remove-an-object-from-dcom-config-dcomcnfg

Answer (score 1):

Every COM entry is refered to by it's GUID in the registry.
So to find all references to your entry, just right clic/properties (in DCOMCNFG), get the guid, and run a search in regedit.

You will find, at least:
- HKCR\AppID{GUID}
- HKCR\CLSID{GUID}

Additionnal entries / replacement in Wow6432Node, display name, and DLL-specific registration, everything can be found using the GUID.

I recommend to be very careful about deleting those entries though.

Comment: Thanks Geod24 for your response.
Is there any tool available which will handle this smartly ?